pdfcpu: To impose a document
I have a 10-page document, each "electronic" page of which corresponds to a separate "paper" page.
I want to merge each two pages into a page spread, so that the 1st "electronic" page will correspond to "paper" pages 1 and 2, the 2nd "electronic" page to "paper" pages 3 and 4, and so on, using pdfcpu (I know how to do it using other popular PDF processors, and my interest is pdfcpu only).
For this, I use
pdfcpu nup -- "formsize:A4L" output.pdf 2 input.pdf

But I'm not really happy with this solution because I would prefer to preserve the original dimensions. That is, if the pages of the input document are 4.85 x 7.85 inches, the spreads of the output document should be 9.7 x 7.85 inches.
I asked the developer, without ever mentioning my current workaround, and he replied "There is orientation and enforce to play around with". I tried this as well, but with no luck yet:

pdfcpu nup -- "orientation:<...>"  output.pdf 2 input.pdf: No matter which orientation I choose (rd, dr, ...), the output file looks the same as if I don't use orientation at all.

pdfcpu nup -- "orientation:<...>, enforce:true"  output.pdf 2 input.pdf: No matter which orientation I choose, there is the ambiguous parameter prefix "enforce" error.



From the data given without a sample the following should work (another option is to remove the division) nup needs dimensions so as to force rotation, whilst grid does not.
pdfcpu nup -- "di:698.4 565.2" out.pdf 2 in.pdf

or

pdfcpu grid -- "bo:f" out.pdf 1 2 in.pdf


Beware any "collateral damage". The fonts are unaffected, but the links in the source TOC are naturally no longer valid and not carried over in the spread pages. Any "Links" (often bookmarks too) need export to a text editor and then re inserted with new page areas.


i don't want to use any hard coded values

The second solution works, thank you! Could you explain, why it is necessary to use grid here? I don't mean to be unthankful, but it seems there should be a more straightforward solution. FWIW, I have uploaded a test file here: https://github.com/jsx97/test/blob/main/input.pdf

Due to the design of A-series paper sizes, you can easily set the paper size to the next larger size. For example, for an A4 original document, you can set the output to A3, which is twice the size of A4.
pdfcpu nup -- "formsize:A3L" output.pdf 2 input.pdf


Hello. Yes, I know how the A-series designed. But I don't need A3. I want the pages (from the user's perspective: page spreads) of the output file to be the same height and twice width as the pages of the input file. That's it.
